# Python tree traversal and sorting groups of items inside sorted list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, tree

I am traversing non-binary tree, I have a function to calc height of the node and number of children. WHat I want to do is to sort children of my node first by height, and inside each height group I want it to be sorted by number of children

eg:

```
      a
   /     \
  b       c
 /|\     /
d e f   g
       /
      h
```

so when I traverse tree:

```
def orderTree(node):        
   if "children" in node:
        if node['children']:
            node['children'].sort(key=findHeight)
            node['children'].sort(key=countChildren)

            for child in node['children']:
                print(child['name'])
                orderTree(child)
```

with this code I go = > a,c,g,h,b,d,e,f 
but what I need is = > a,b,d,e,f,c,g,h

Any Idea how to sort sorted group of items inside python list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called "multi-field sorting",

To sort a list of nodes by their height and then by their number of children simply give `sort` the following function as `key`:

```
lambda x : (findHeight(x), children(x))
```

This simply returns a tuple of (height, children). And then `sort` uses this tuple to compare two nodes.

Code:

```
def orderTree(node):
   # I combined the two ifs
   if "children" in node and node['children']:
        node['children'].sort(key= lambda x : (findHeight(x), children(x) ) )

        for child in node['children']:
            print(child['name'])
            orderTree(child)
```

Lets say I have
 `A = (a,b)` and `B = (x, y)`

These two tuples will be compared like this:

```
def compare_tuple(A, B):
    if A[0] != B[0]: return A[0] < B[0]
    else: return A[1] < B[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of tree traversal you are after is called pre-order. It is hard to understand your code without knowing the full structure. But it looks like you are looking at the children from the root node first then traversing down.

I think you want to open the first child node and then keep traversing through that. For pre-order it should be something like.

```
node
node.left
node.right
```

This is a good reference 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/